# Is there any way to pass a variable to evaluate or alternatively load a json file from within evaluate?

Tags: javascript, json, casperjs

I'm trying to pass some data located in a local JSON file into casper.evaluate but it doesn't seem to be accessible from there. I've tried loading it from outside evaluate but I can't read it inside evaluate. I've also tried to load it from within evaluate as follows:

```
var keyWords = casper.evaluate(function () {
  // load local JSON file
  var json = require('../keywords.json');
  return json;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(keyWords));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass JSON as an argument to [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) using the following method:

```
var keyWords = casper.evaluate(function (json) {
  return json;
}, json);
```

A full program to accomplish this task would look something like this:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://example.com/');

casper.then(function () {
  var json = require('../keywords.json');

  var keyWords = this.evaluate(function (json) {
    return json;
  }, json);

  this.echo(JSON.stringify(keyWords));
});

casper.run();
```